# TSQL 'Invalid column name' error on value of sproc parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

here's my code:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(600)

SET @SQL = 
'SELECT     CategoryID, SubCategoryID, ReportedNumber
FROM    tblStatistics
WHERE   UnitCode = ' + @unitCode +
' AND   FiscYear = ' + @currYEAR

EXEC (@SQL)
```

When i run this sproc with unitCode = 'COB' and currYEAR = '10', i get the following error:

```
Invalid column name 'COB'.
```

Does anyone know why?

thx!

Comment: A good way to test your dynamic SQL is to say `PRINT @SQL` instead of `EXEC (@SQL)`... that way you can take a look at the SQL statement that you're expecting to run :)

Answer (score 8):

That's a nice SQL injection vulnerability there.

Start by rewriting it this way, using bind parameters:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL =
    'SELECT CategoryID, SubCategoryID, ReportedNumber ' +
    'FROM tblStatistics ' +
    'WHERE UnitCode = @UnitCode ' +
    'AND FiscYear = @CurrYear'

EXEC sp_executesql
    @SQL,
    '@UnitCode varchar(10), @CurrYear int',
    @UnitCode = 'COB',
    @FiscYear = 10
```

Comment: @Daria: What?  You don't do SQL injection "tests", you design your scripts and code to prevent it in the first place.  The code you posted is a SQL injection vulnerability - period.  This is the *only* correct way to write dynamic SQL with parameters, and it will solve your error here at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put quotes around the values in the SQL:

```
'SELECT     CategoryID, SubCategoryID, ReportedNumber
FROM    tblStatistics
WHERE   UnitCode = ''' + @unitCode +
''' AND   FiscYear = ''' + @currYEAR + ''''
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have quotes inside your quotes - SQL essentially sees

```
WHERE UnitCode = COB
```

and COB must not be a column. But why are you building the SQL this way? Why not

```
SELECT CategoryID, SubCategoryID, ReportedNumber
  FROM tblStatistics
 WHERE UnitCode = @unitCode
   AND FiscYear = @currYear
```

Comment: Correct you do not need to write dynamic sql just to pass parameters to your select statement inside of a stored procedure.

Comment: that's not my complete code, just an example to get across my error issue.  i do have a good reason for making it dynamic.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If we can assume that UnitCode is a `VARCHAR` field you'd have to add quotes around the @unitcode variable.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(600) 

SET @SQL =  
'SELECT     CategoryID, SubCategoryID, ReportedNumber 
 FROM    tblStatistics 
 WHERE   UnitCode = ''' + @unitCode + ''''
' AND   FiscYear = ' + @currYEAR 

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: You're adding quotes, not parentheses... I've heard a million other people use the wrong word there before :P